# How to get row from JTable Depending on a JCombox Value Selection?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

If I click on the combobox value then the JTable row with same value as the selected combobox should only get display.
For example:

```
ID      Name.              Category 
101.   Dumplings           Chicken
102.   Pizza               Cheese
```

When I select chicken in combobox, the row of JTable with Chicken that is the first row should only get displayed.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [RowFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/RowFilter.html).

You install a RowFilter on a [TableRowSorter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html):

```
TableRowSorter<Dish> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
table.setRowSorter(sorter);

int categoryColumnIndex = 2;

combobox.addActionListener(e -> {
    String value = combobox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    sorter.setRowFilter(
        RowFilter.regexFilter(
            Pattern.quote(value),
            categoryColumnIndex));
});
```

Comment: Is there any alternatives without installing RowFilter?

Comment: Yes, you can always write your own subclass of AbstractTableModel, and add a filtering method to it.